# How to do negative testing in Stripe using Apple Pay and Google Pay?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I have implemented Apple Pay and Google Pay in [Stripe's Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button)

The implementation is working perfectly. However, I need to do some negative testing using some cards that will show an error while doing a payment flow. For example,

1. To test generic decline, `4000000000000002`
2. To test Lost card decline, `4000000000009987`

How can I test these negative scenarios using **Apple Pay** and **Google Pay** in **Stripe's Payment Request**?

So far I have tried this code,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      console.log("NO STRIPE", stripe, elements)
      return;
    }
   
    if (stripe && !paymentRequest) {
      const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        total: {
          label: 'Total Amount',
          amount: 2000,
        },
      });
  
      pr.canMakePayment().then(result => {
        if (!result?.applePay && !result?.googlePay && !result?.lin) {
          return
        }

        if (result) {
          setPaymentRequest(pr);
        } else {
        }
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log("error", e );
      });

    }
  }, [stripe]);
```

I have also gone through [Stripe Testing Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/testing). But have not found any solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

You mostly can't do this since you can't add those test cards to Google/Apple wallets. Generally you would stub it. So in the `on.("paymentmethod")` event , change your code to ignore the actual payment method `pm_xxx` from the event, and instead pass the string `pm_card_visa_chargeDeclined` into the next part of your code.

One option that might work is to add those testcards as 'autofill' cards in  chrome://settings/autofill and then try viewing the page using the PaymentRequestButton in an incognito Chrome window.